# userid_expires nginx

Tags: nginx

I need to define a cookie on with nginx according to this doc : http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUseridModule
But when I set :

```
userid          on;
userid_name     SessionStatId;
userid_domain   orange.fr;
userid_path     /;
userid_expires  8y;
```

Expire is set to session and not ten years as defined!

Do you know why and how can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it !
In my Firefox configuration, I've ajust it to clean all cookies by firefox closure.
So all cookies were setted to expire at the end of session. It was that !